# dmvnorm MVN density - RcppArmadillo implementation slower than R package including a bit of Fortran

Tags: r, rcpp

The **solution** is now online in the **[Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/dmvnorm_arma/)**

---

I re-implemented dmvnorm from the mvtnorm package in RcppArmadillo. I somehow like Armadillo, but I guess it would also work in plain Rcpp. The approach from dmvnorm is based on the mahalanobis distance, so I have a function for that and then the multivariate normal density function.

Let me show you my code:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec mahalanobis_arma( arma::mat x ,  arma::mat mu, arma::mat sigma ){

  int n = x.n_rows;
  arma::vec md(n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        arma::mat x_i = x.row(i) - mu;
        arma::mat Y = arma::solve( sigma, arma::trans(x_i) );
        md(i) = arma::as_scalar(x_i * Y);
    }
    return md;

    }



// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec dmvnorm ( arma::mat x,  arma::mat mean,  arma::mat sigma, bool log){ 

arma::vec distval = mahalanobis_arma(x,  mean, sigma);

    double logdet = sum(arma::log(arma::eig_sym(sigma)));
    double log2pi = 1.8378770664093454835606594728112352797227949472755668;
    arma::vec logretval = -( (x.n_cols * log2pi + logdet + distval)/2  ) ;

       if(log){ 
         return(logretval);

       }else { 
       return(exp(logretval));
         }
}
```

So, and not to my big disappointment:

simulate some data

```
sigma <- matrix(c(4,2,2,3), ncol=2)
x <- rmvnorm(n=5000000, mean=c(1,2), sigma=sigma, method="chol")
```

and benchmark

```
system.time(mvtnorm::dmvnorm(x,t(1:2),.2+diag(2),F))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.05    0.02    0.06 

system.time(dmvnorm(x,t(1:2),.2+diag(2),F))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.12    0.02    0.14
```

No!!!!!! :-(

[EDIT]

The **questions** are:
1) Why is the RcppArmadillo implementation slower than a plain R implementation?
2) How do I create an Rcpp/RcppArmadillo implementation that beats the R implementation?

[EDIT 2]

I put in the mahalanobis_arma into the mvtnorm::dmvnorm function and it also slows down.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is

Comment: look at the code of `mvtnorm::dmvnorm`.  It uses `eigen`, which is calling LAPACK code for symmetric eigenvalues ... it may be hard to get faster for this very standard piece of computational linear algebra ...

Comment: well, but Armadillo is supposed to be fast with linear algebra as well ... I think it uses Lapack. Is there so much overhead when calling an Rcpp function? That would surprise me. Besides, the mahalanobis distance computation should be faster in Rcpp.

Comment: If the bulk of the calculations are going to be performed by the same linear algebra library between the two implementaions, why do you expect to see a significant improvement?

Comment: I don't expect a big improvement. I need dmvnorm as part of a larger Rcpp project. However, there should be no *decrease* in performance. I mean how can it take twice as long now? Maybe I can replace arma::solve with something that takes advantage of the symmetric property?

Comment: This just shows you can write slow code in any language. :) Why not simply call `mvtnorm::dmvnorm` from C++?

Comment: I haven't done that before. Do I have to use RInside for that? And is there no penalty for calling R in C? I'd be calling the function quite often. And still, it's hard for me to accept that there is such a slowdown. It is really simple code. Dirk? Are you reading this?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: I found this related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111449/calling-an-r-function-using-inline-and-rcpp-is-still-just-as-slow-as-original-r?rq=1 Seems like an option to minimize slowdown. But does not help much with loops.

Comment: Your question title is misleading. RCppArmadillo is not slower than R; it's slower than _R plus Fortran_. The Fortran bit happens to be more important than the R bit here.

Comment: @HongOoi: You're right. The R package uses Fortran, I should mention that. However, I am also experiencing a slowdown replacing native R mahalanobis with Rcpp mahalanobis.

Comment: But ... R mahalanobis calls `sweep`, and `solve`, and `rowSums`, all of which are fast/coded in C or FORTRAN ... `solve` calls LAPACK again.

Comment: the bottom line of this is that re-coding in lower-level languages generally only helps *if the relevant operations are not already dropping through to compiled binary code in the original R functions* ...

Comment: @BenBolker: You are missing the point. I am writing an entire MCMC sampler in Rcpp. Calling R from within C is a bit silly here, since I am parallelizing with openMP and want to avoid costly memory transfers between the languages. Thus I need a C implementation of some standard functions. We are talking about a MVN density, which I think is pretty standard. And I think standard things should not be slower in Rcpp than in some R package. I mean, what's next: call R to compute an inverse? A multiplication? There ought to be a fast MVN density for most MCMC problems.

Comment: A few more questions (comments). (1) is the benchmarking you've done here representative of what you need to do? e.g., is this the relevant size of matrix? (The relative timings might depend on scale.) (2) I don't know what the penalties are of calling R from C; you could experiment. (3) You might try a benchmark (with the `rbenchmark` or `microbenchmark` package) with more replications: I'm not sure that a single realization is reliable for identifying a difference of 0.07 seconds. (4) is this step *the* main bottleneck, or are there other steps you should also be worrying about?

Comment: Fundamentally, the problem is that you're dealing with operations that are already pretty highly optimized. You're going to have to attend to quite fine details if you want to do better ...

Comment: @BenBolker: Good points. 1) The matrix has more rows but less columns than my typical problem. So yes, I should benchmark this within the final code/model. 3) Right, I just reran the system.time and data simulation 10 times and results looked quite consistent. I can get more accurate benchmarks though. 4) There also also other steps, but this one is quite important. I'll just continue with my code and worry about this again later. Still, dmvnorm is quite important in MCMC. Mixture of Normals as part of the Likelihood and/or Prior are ubiquitous.

Comment: @Inferrator: All the other comments were already on point.  You will want to learn about profiling to actually gather _evidence_ rather than making sweeping statements (without any empirical backing) as you have done here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a faster implementation of the mahalanobis distance, you just have to re-write your algorithm and mimic the one used by R. It's pretty straightforward

I modified a little bit your function `mahalanobis_arma` to turn `mu` to a `rowvec`.

Basically I just translated the R code to RcppArmadillo

```
mahalanobis
function (x, center, cov, inverted = FALSE, ...) 
{
    x <- if (is.vector(x)) 
        matrix(x, ncol = length(x))
    else as.matrix(x)
    x <- sweep(x, 2, center)
    if (!inverted) 
        cov <- solve(cov, ...)
    setNames(rowSums((x %*% cov) * x), rownames(x))
}
<bytecode: 0x6e5b408>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Here it is

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec Mahalanobis(arma::mat x, arma::rowvec center, arma::mat cov){
    int n = x.n_rows;
    arma::mat x_cen;
    x_cen.copy_size(x);
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        x_cen.row(i) = x.row(i) - center;
    }
    return sum((x_cen * cov.i()) % x_cen, 1);    
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec mahalanobis_arma( arma::mat x ,  arma::rowvec mu, arma::mat sigma ){

  int n = x.n_rows;
  arma::vec md(n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        arma::mat x_i = x.row(i) - mu;
        arma::mat Y = arma::solve( sigma, arma::trans(x_i) );
        md(i) = arma::as_scalar(x_i * Y);
    }
    return md;

    }
```

Now, let's compare this new armadillo version (`Mahalanobis`), your first version (`mahalanobis_arma`) and the R implementation (`mahalanobis`).

I save this Cpp code as `mahalanobis.cpp`

```
require(RcppArmadillo)
sourceCpp("mahalanobis.cpp")

set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(10000 * 10), ncol = 10)
Sx <- cov(x)


all.equal(c(Mahalanobis(x, colMeans(x), Sx))
          ,mahalanobis(x, colMeans(x), Sx))
## [1] TRUE

all.equal(mahalanobis_arma(x, colMeans(x), Sx)
          ,Mahalanobis(x, colMeans(x), Sx))
## [1] TRUE


require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(Mahalanobis(x, colMeans(x), Sx),
          mahalanobis(x, colMeans(x), Sx),
          mahalanobis_arma(x, colMeans(x), Sx),
          order = "elapsed")


##                                   test replications elapsed
## 1      Mahalanobis(x, colMeans(x), Sx)          100   0.124
## 2      mahalanobis(x, colMeans(x), Sx)          100   0.741
## 3 mahalanobis_arma(x, colMeans(x), Sx)          100   4.509
##   relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
## 1    1.000     0.173    0.077          0         0
## 2    5.976     0.804    0.670          0         0
## 3   36.363     4.386    4.626          0         0
```

As you can see the new implementation is faster than the R one. 
I'm pretty sure that we can do better here by using cholesky decomposition to solve the covariance matrix or by using other matrix decomposition.

Finally, we can just plug this `Mahalanobis` function into your `dmvnorm` and test it :

```
require(mvtnorm)
set.seed(1)
sigma <- matrix(c(4, 2, 2, 3), ncol = 2)
x <- rmvnorm(n = 5000000, mean = c(1, 2), sigma = sigma, method = "chol")


all.equal(mvtnorm::dmvnorm(x, t(1:2), .2 + diag(2), FALSE),
          c(dmvnorm(x, t(1:2), .2+diag(2), FALSE)))
## [1] TRUE

benchmark(mvtnorm::dmvnorm(x, t(1:2), .2 + diag(2), FALSE),
          dmvnorm(x, t(1:2), .2+diag(2), FALSE),
          order = "elapsed")

##                                                test replications
## 2          dmvnorm(x, t(1:2), 0.2 + diag(2), FALSE)          100
## 1 mvtnorm::dmvnorm(x, t(1:2), 0.2 + diag(2), FALSE)          100
##   elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
## 2  35.366    1.000    31.117    4.193          0         0
## 1  60.770    1.718    56.666   13.236          0         0
```

It almost twice as fast now.

Comment: Just one more thing: I might have different means. So I have to subtract them in advance, and then run this with mean 0.

Comment: @Inferrator You can turn `mu` to `mat` again by making sure that you substract it carefully to `x` (row wise) and the dimension are adequate.

Comment: Right. Great, thanks much! Simple but smart solution. Wouldn't this be nice for the Rcpp gallery?

Comment: I put everything together in a gist and added openMP: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5987975 - Just run Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-fopenmp")
Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-fopenmp") in R and then use sourceCpp

Comment: @Inferrator Well I think it could be a nice addition to Rcpp gallery, I think they accept gist if you want to add an entry.

Comment: @dickoa: Yes, it is a nice answer and it should be an addition to the Gallery :-). Also, I just stuck a new 'openmp' plugin into Rcpp's SVN.  If you can update from SVN you could use that.

Comment: @Inferrator Just let me know when you want to add it to the gallery. here's my github : https://github.com/dickoa.

Comment: @Inferrator I just checked, well done. I added a small comment to the commit to simplify a little the `log2pi` part of the code.

Comment: @Inferrator Here it is, Thanks again, it was fun !!  http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/dmvnorm_arma/