# first derivative of multivariate normal/gaussian with rcpp and RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to implement the first derivative of the multivariate normal distribution in R building on the `rcpp` implementation of the multivariate normal distribution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617618/dmvnorm-mvn-density-rcpparmadillo-implementation-slower-than-r-package-includi) and [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/dmvnorm_arma/).

Here is a quick R implementation

```
mvnormDeriv = function(..., mu=rep(0,length(list(...))), sigma=diag(length(list(...)))) {
    if(sd(laply(list(...),length))!=0)
        stop("The vectors not same length.")
    fn = function(x) -1 * c((1/sqrt(det(2*pi*sigma))) * exp(-0.5*t(x-mu)%*%solve(sigma)%*%(x-mu))) * solve(sigma,(x-mu))
    out = t(apply(cbind(...),1,fn))
    colnames(out) = c('x', 'y')
    return(out[,1])
}
```

and some test data with benchmark:

```
set.seed(123456789)
sigma = rWishart(1, 2, diag(2))
means = rnorm(2)
X     = rmvnorm(10000, means, sigma[,,1])
x1    = X[,1]
x2    = X[,2]
benchmark(mvnormDeriv(x1,x2,mu=means,sigma=sigma),
    order="relative", replications=5)[,1:4]
```

The formula can be found in the matrix cookbook (2012), formula 346.

I failed to modify the `rcpp` implementation of the multivariate normal from [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/dmvnorm_arma/). Here is some code, which I used to try

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec dmvnormDeriv_arma(arma::mat x,  SEXP mu_sexp, arma::mat sigma, bool log = false) {

    // create Rcpp vector and matrix from SEXP arguments
    Rcpp::NumericVector mu_rcpp(mu_sexp);
    // create views for arma objects(reuses memory and avoids extra copy)
    arma::vec mu_vec(mu_rcpp.begin(), mu_rcpp.size(), false);
    arma::rowvec mu(mu_rcpp.begin(), mu_rcpp.size(), false);

    // return(mu_vec);
    arma::vec distval = Mahalanobis(x,  mu, sigma);
    double logdet = sum(arma::log(arma::eig_sym(sigma)));
    double log2pi = std::log(2.0 * M_PI);
    arma::vec val = exp(-( (x.n_cols * log2pi + logdet + distval)/2));

    // x.each_row() -= mu;
    // arma::vec val2 = solve(sigma, x.row(1));
    // arma::vec retval = -1 * val(1) * solve(sigma, x.row(1)-mu_vec);

    return(val);
}
```

This is not complete, of course. Any ideas how I can implement the `* solve(sigma,(x-mu))` part in `rcpp` or with `Armadillo`? I have problems handling the different variables types and running the solve for each row of x.

Comment: Isn't that `solve()` just a (possibly Matlab-)shorthand for `inv()`? In which case you can take it straight from the Armadillo docs. [ And we're about to update the Gallery post you referred to; keep an eye out for it.  And then submit one with this :) ]

Comment: Thanks, I have added a solution below. I will submit something for the Gallery if that is of interest. Let me know if you have suggestions for improvements.

Comment: Slightly OT but you mentioned using the Matrix Cookbook from 2012, can you provide a link in the question? It's quite hard to find. On-topic, it may have value in making the question a bit more self-contained. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution based on `RcppArmadillo`. It is over 100 times faster than the R implementation. First, the c++ implementation, which relies on [this rcpp gallery example](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/dmvnorm_arma/).

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat dmvnormderiv_arma(arma::mat x, arma::rowvec mean, arma::mat sigma, bool log = false) {
    // get result for mv normal
    arma::vec distval = Mahalanobis(x,  mean, sigma);
    double logdet = sum(arma::log(arma::eig_sym(sigma)));
    double log2pi = std::log(2.0 * M_PI);
    arma::vec mvnorm = exp(-( (x.n_cols * log2pi + logdet + distval)/2));

    // create output matrix with one column for each derivative
    int n = x.n_rows;
    arma::mat deriv;
    deriv.copy_size(x);
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        deriv.row(i) = -1 * mvnorm(i) * trans(solve(sigma, trans(x.row(i) - mean)));
    }

    return(deriv);
}
```

And two R implementations. One is pure R and one is based on `dmvnorm` in the package `mvtnorm`.

```
library('RcppArmadillo')
library('mvtnorm')
library('rbenchmark')
sourceCpp('mvnorm.cpp')

mvnormDeriv = function(X, mu=rep(0,ncol(X)), sigma=diag(ncol(X))) {
    fn = function(x) -1 * c((1/sqrt(det(2*pi*sigma))) * exp(-0.5*t(x-mu)%*%solve(sigma)%*%(x-mu))) * solve(sigma,(x-mu))
    out = t(apply(X,1,fn))
    return(out)
}
dmvnormDeriv = function(X, mean, sigma) {
    if (is.vector(X)) X <- matrix(X, ncol = length(X))
    if (missing(mean)) mean <- rep(0, length = ncol(X))
    if (missing(sigma)) sigma <- diag(ncol(X))
    n = nrow(X)
    mvnorm = dmvnorm(X, mean = mean, sigma = sigma)
    deriv = array(NA,c(n,ncol(X)))
    for (i in 1:n)
        deriv[i,] = -mvnorm[i] * solve(sigma,(X[i,]-mean))
    return(deriv)
}
```

Finally some benchmarks:

```
set.seed(123456789)
sigma = rWishart(1, 2, diag(2))[,,1]
means = rnorm(2)
X     = rmvnorm(10000, means, sigma)

benchmark(dmvnormderiv_arma(X,means,sigma),
        mvnormDeriv(X,mu=means,sigma=sigma),
        dmvnormDeriv(X,mean=means,sigma=sigma),
        order="relative", replications=5)[,1:4]

                                          test replications elapsed
1           dmvnormderiv_arma(X, means, sigma)            5   0.016
3 dmvnormDeriv(X, mean = means, sigma = sigma)            5   2.118
2    mvnormDeriv(X, mu = means, sigma = sigma)            5   5.939
  relative
1    1.000
3  132.375
2  371.187
```

Comment: Nicely done. That looks pretty nice, and almost ready. Take a look at the existing `.Rmd` (or, if you prefer, `.cpp`) files there and either send me something by mail, or fork and do the pull request thing common on Github.

Comment: Instead of doing sum(arma::log(arma::eig_sym(sigma))), the [log_det()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#log_det) might be more efficient

Comment: Dirk, [here](https://gist.github.com/jlegewie/6485612) is a gist with the Rmd file. I will add an issue to the gallery github page so the discussion can continue there.