# Rcpp - how to call R function from Rcpp function in Shiny

Tags: c++, r, shiny, rcpp

i just new with rcpp, i have a problem with my rcpp function, when i directly run App, the program display error *could not find function "krit"*. but when i run the function partially with **CTRL+R** and then run App the program is running well. is there a code for call R function from rcpp function in shiny that i must not run the function partially? in other words, when i directly run App the shiny will running well. this is the example code...

server

```
library(shiny)
library(Rcpp)
krit <- function(n){
  mat <- matrix(1,n,1)
  return(mat)
}
cppFunction('
            NumericMatrix tes1(int n){
            Function krit("krit");
            NumericMatrix test = krit(n+1);
            return(test);
            }
            ')

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$testing <- renderUI({
    list(
    renderPrint(tes1(3))
    )
  })

})
```

ui

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny Text"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

    ),
    mainPanel(

      uiOutput("testing")
    )
  )
))
```

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225662/calling-a-user-defined-r-function-from-c-using-rcpp

Comment: I put the code I need for our various shiny apps into _packages_ which avoids the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scoping issue regarding how `shiny` and `Rcpp` view the different environments.

What's happening is an issue with accessing the global environment using...

1) Standard `Rcpp::Function` magic

```
Rcpp::Function krit("krit");
```

2) `Rcpp::Environment` with a global pull yields a missing value.

```
Rcpp::Environment env = Environment::global_env();
Rcpp::Function krit = env("krit");
```

Error:

> file3d3f43b856e05.cpp:9:45: error: no match for call to '(Rcpp::Environment) (const char [5])'

Thus, the best that can be done to resolve this scoping issue is to pass the R function that you want to use into the compiled C++ function and call it. e.g.

```
NumericMatrix tes1(int n, Rcpp::Function krit)
```

Or, you will need to modify the `server.R` to:

```
library(shiny)
library(Rcpp)

krit <- function(n){
  mat <- matrix(1,n,1)
  return(mat)
}

cppFunction('
            // Added krit as a function pass
            NumericMatrix tes1(int n, Rcpp::Function krit){
            NumericMatrix test = krit(n+1);
            return(test);
            }
            ')

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$testing <- renderUI({
    list(
      # Added parameter to `tes1` to pass in krit.
      renderPrint(tes1(n = 3, krit = krit))
    )
  })

})
```

Thus, you should get:

[image: shiny_text]