# Alternatives to calling an R function from Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I was reading up very generic advice from lots of references, including the very introduction from Rcpp homepage and other posts in stackoverflow, such as [Calling an R function using inline and rcpp is still just as low as original R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111449/calling-an-r-function-using-inline-and-rcpp-is-still-just-as-slow-as-original-r).

My concern is that as we are building a CRAN package, evaluation of a posterior distribution (yes, I'm Bayesian) should be declared in R. Main algorithm was written in Rcpp, `NumericMatrix sampling(NumericVector x, Function func)`.
I tried (1) simply inputting R function and (2) define an object with `cppFunction` to be passed into cpp script. It has, of course, no performance difference as expected.

So my main question should be

> Should there be other ways to pass an evaluting function `func` as an input argument to generic Rcpp script of ours if its form in C/C++ is provided by an user ?

I've been struggling with this issue for quite a long time - looking through Rcpp gallery and its related projects. Since our target audience is much less literate in coding than I am, we hope specifying a function should not far exceed than simply writing an inline function. We would really appreciate any advice in advance.

Comment: That is a pretty long-winded question. The answer is *simple*: to get *compiled speed* you need to call (or supply) a *compiled* function.  Calling an R function from compiled code ... still calls an R function. No Free Lunch.

Comment: I *do* show how to pass *user-supplied compiled functions* into repeated evaluations -- see RcppDE which does it for differential evolution. Resampling is no different.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: This is an interesting topic... looking at RcppDE source code it looks like you're basically wrapping a function pointer inside a `Rcpp::XPtr` am I right ?

Comment: Yes. That worked before as well, but as with many things provided by Rcpp it is easier now thanks to wrappers and glue.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I saw many of your replies to this sort of questions so I feel really sorry as well as gratuitous for referring to RcppDE. Before, I had NULL idea on what to look for. Thanks again.

Comment: This is _not_ the easiest of topics but worth exploring. Study RcppDE, I think we have one or two XPtr examples at the gallery ... and let's then create a new one for custom sampler. "In a way" this is what Stan and Nimble do (with of course more structure and much more hand-holding).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: I just added an answer with an example inspired by RcppDE. If I didn't make any big mistake, it seems the `R<->Rcpp` transition overhead disappears when we pass a compiled function to Rcpp (as expected). Thanks for pointing out RcppDE, I learned something very useful today :)

Comment: @digEmAll Thanks to Dirk and you, we become able to jump over big chasms, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to create an example, inspired by RcppDE.

First we define a C++ function which calls n-times a "sum" function passed as argument. The given function can be an R function or a `xptr<>` wrapping a function pointer.
Code:

```
require(Rcpp)

# C++ function which calls a given "sum" function n-times.
# The passed function can be an R function or 
# an xptr wrapping a function pointer.
sourceCpp(code="
#include <Rcpp.h>

typedef double (*sumFnPtr)(Rcpp::NumericVector);

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector callSumFunctionNTimes(SEXP sumFn, Rcpp::NumericVector toSum,int times){
  Rcpp::NumericVector output(times);
  switch (TYPEOF(sumFn)){ 
    case EXTPTRSXP:
    {
      Rcpp::XPtr<sumFnPtr> xptr = Rcpp::as< Rcpp::XPtr<sumFnPtr> >(sumFn);
      for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
        output[i] = (*(xptr))(toSum);
      }
      break;
    }
    // we suppose is a R function
    default: 
    {
      Rcpp::Function fn = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::Function>(sumFn);
      for(int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        output[i] = Rcpp::as<double>( fn(toSum) );
      break;
    }
  }
  return output;
}
")
```

Then, in C++ we define "mySum" function and another function returning a `xptr<>` wrapping it.
Code :

```
require(Rcpp)

# Here we define the sum function in C++ and we also 
# define a function returning a xptr wrapping the function
sourceCpp(code="
#include <Rcpp.h>

typedef double (*sumFnPtr)(Rcpp::NumericVector);

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double mySum(Rcpp::NumericVector toSum){
  double s = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < toSum.length(); i++){
    s += toSum[i];
  }
  return s;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP getSumFunctionPtr(){
  return Rcpp::XPtr<sumFnPtr>(new sumFnPtr(&mySum));
}
")
```

Finally, we define a function which computes all the sums in C++ (i.e. without receiving the function as argument). Code :

```
require(Rcpp)

sourceCpp(code="
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector doEverythingInCpp(Rcpp::NumericVector toSum, int times){
  Rcpp::NumericVector output(times);
  for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
    double s = 0;
    for(int j =0; j < toSum.length();j++){
      s += toSum[j];
    }
    output[i] = s;
  }
}

")
```

Let's test what happens when :

- TEST 1 : we call an R function (sum) 1 million times
- TEST 2 : we call an Rcpp function (mySum) 1 million times
- TEST 3 : we call an Rcpp function wrapped in `xptr<>` 1 million times
- TEST 4 : we do everything in C++ (i.e. we compute the sum 1 million times in C++)

Code:

```
# TEST 1
system.time(callSumFunctionNTimes(sum,1:100,1e6))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 13.45    0.00   13.45 

# TEST 2
system.time(callSumFunctionNTimes(mySum,1:100,1e6))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 13.97    0.00   13.97

# TEST 3
mySumFunctionnPtr <- getSumFunctionPtr()
system.time(callSumFunctionNTimes(mySumFunctionnPtr,1:100,1e6))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.28    0.00    0.29

# TEST 4
system.time(doEverythingInCpp(1:100,1e6))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.27    0.00    0.27
```

As you can see the `R <-> C++` transition overhead disappears when we pass a compiled function (i.e. the function pointer wrapped in an `xptr<>`) to C++, in fact the TEST 3 and 4 have basically the same performance.

Comment: Can you make it have fewer `SEXP` types?

Comment: Thanks for nice introductory example. I was also looking through RcppDE and feels similar. BTW, @DirkEddelbuettel, since I don't have enough stackoverflow 'reputations' to add a comment, WideLM, which was using both Rcpp and CUDA, seems to be removed from CRAN. Do you happen to encounter any other packages to use BOTH rcpp and cuda ?

Comment: [This one](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/gpuR/index.html) does Rcpp and OpenCL.